# encoding vertex positions into textures, positions dont match and index is always zero

Tags: c#, glsl

I am trying to make a tool to encode vertex positions into a texture. The tool takes a sequence of Wavefront obj files and exports 2 textures. I am, for the most part, following [this guide](https://medium.com/tech-at-wildlife-studios/texture-animation-techniques-1daecb316657). I am using C# and Veldrid for my program. My program also shows a preview to see what the result looks like. I am having trouble getting my preview to use the textures correctly. The textures have the below mapping.

Texture 1:

- RG - X Position
- BA - Y Position

Texture 2:

- RG - Z Position
- BA - Normals, eventually haven't gotten their yet.

I have two issues. My first issue is the decoded position is not being decoded correctly. The second issue is that `gl_VertexIndex` seems to always be zero.

For my first issue, in order to see what was going on, I set the texture coords for the texture to 0, 0 to sample the first vertex of the first frame. I also removed any view transformation so that I could see the actual values in renderdoc.

In Renderdoc, the `VS_Input` is 11.67803, 1.00, -11.06608 and the `VS_Out` is 5.75159, 1.99283, -5.03286. When using `gl_VertexIndex`, all the vertices for `VS_Out` read the same thing.

[image: Image from render doc]

```c
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 Normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 TexCoords;
layout(location = 3) in uint Id;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 outNormal;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 outDebug;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform MVP {
    mat4 Model;
    mat4 View;
    mat4 Projection;
};

layout(set=0, binding=1) uniform sampler textureSampler;
layout(set=0, binding=2) uniform texture2D posTex;
layout(set=0, binding=3) uniform texture2D normalTex;

float RemapRange(float value, float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2){
    return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
}

float DecodeFloatRG (vec2 enc){
  vec2 kDecodeDot = vec2 (1.0, 1 / 255.0);
  return dot(enc, kDecodeDot);
}

void main(){
    outDebug = Projection * View * Model * vec4(Position, 1.0f);

    vec2 coords = vec2(0, 0);
    vec4 pos = textureLod(sampler2D(posTex, textureSampler), coords, 0);
    vec4 normal = textureLod(sampler2D(normalTex, textureSampler), coords, 0);

    vec3 decodedPos;

    decodedPos.x = DecodeFloatRG(pos.xy);
    decodedPos.y = DecodeFloatRG(pos.zw);
    decodedPos.z = DecodeFloatRG(normal.xy);

    float x = RemapRange(decodedPos.x, 0.0f, 1.0f, -13.0f, 13.0f); //right now this is hardcoded
    float y = RemapRange(decodedPos.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, -13.0f, 13.0f);
    float z = RemapRange(decodedPos.z, 0.0f, 1.0f, -13.0f, 13.0f);

    //gl_Position = Projection * View * Model * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
    //gl_Position = vec4(Position, 1.0f);

    outNormal = Normal;
}
```

For the second issue, the shader is the same, but instead I'm using:

```cs
coords = vec2(gl_VertexIndex, 0)
```

I'm also not sure that using vertex index is the best way to go about this, as it seems like most game engines don't have this exposed.

On the CPU side, I encode the textures using the below:

```cs
        //https://forum.unity.com/threads/re-map-a-number-from-one-range-to-another.119437/
        protected float RemapRange(float value, float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2){
            return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
        }

        //https://medium.com/tech-at-wildlife-studios/texture-animation-techniques-1daecb316657
        protected Vector2 EncodeFloatRG (float v){
            Vector2 kEncodeMul = new Vector2(1.0f, 255.0f);
            float kEncodeBit = 1.0f / 255.0f;
            Vector2 enc = kEncodeMul * v;
            
            enc.X = fract(enc.X);
            enc.Y = fract(enc.Y);

            enc.X -= enc.Y * kEncodeBit;
            
            return enc;
        }

        float fract(float x){
            return x - MathF.Floor(x);
        }
```

This is what the loop writing the pixels looks like. There is another one for the second texture, but it's pretty much the same.

```cs
            posImg.Mutate(c => c.ProcessPixelRowsAsVector4(row =>
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < row.Length; x++)
                {
                    var obj = meshes[y];
                    var vertex = obj.Vertices[x];

                    var pixel = new Vector4();

                    float X = RemapRange(vertex.Position.X, bounds.Min, bounds.Max, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                    float Y = RemapRange(vertex.Position.Y, bounds.Min, bounds.Max, 0.0f, 1.0f);


                    var encodedX = EncodeFloatRG(X);
                    var encodedY = EncodeFloatRG(Y);

                    pixel.X = encodedX.X; 
                    pixel.Y = encodedX.Y;
                    pixel.Z = encodedY.X;
                    pixel.W = encodedY.Y;


                    row[x] = pixel;
                }

                y += 1;
            }));
```

How I am creating and loading the textures in veldrid. As far as the sampler goes, it is a `gd.PointSampler`. I have tried turning SRGB on and off on the `ImageSharpTexture()` and using `R8_G8_B8_A8_UNorm_SRgb` and `R8_G8_B8_A8_UNorm` and pretty much any combo of those.

```cs
            var posTex = new Veldrid.ImageSharp.ImageSharpTexture(posPath, false, true);
            var normalTex = new Veldrid.ImageSharp.ImageSharpTexture(normalPath, false, true);

            var posDeviceTex = posTex.CreateDeviceTexture(gd, gd.ResourceFactory);
            var normalDeviceTex = normalTex.CreateDeviceTexture(gd, gd.ResourceFactory);

            var posViewDesc = new TextureViewDescription(posDeviceTex, PixelFormat.R8_G8_B8_A8_UNorm_SRgb);
            var normalViewDesc = new TextureViewDescription(normalDeviceTex, PixelFormat.R8_G8_B8_A8_UNorm_SRgb);

            positionTexture = gd.ResourceFactory.CreateTextureView(posViewDesc);
            normalTexture = gd.ResourceFactory.CreateTextureView(normalViewDesc);
```

EDIT:

I tried hard-coding the value of pixel (0, 0) of the texture in the shader like below. When I do this the result is correct and matches the original vertex position. When reading the pixel values of the texture in the shader and exporting them directly the values are wrong, so I am thinking there is some compression or color space weirdness going on when reading then texture in. Like in the shader the correct value for the pixel at 0,0 should be (0.9490196, 0.03529412, 0.5372549, 0.30588236), but in renderdoc it shows as (0.55492, 0.28516, 0.29102, 0.54314)

[image: Screenshot of the correct values in render doc]

```c
 outDebug = Projection * View * Model * vec4(Position, 1.0f);

    vec2 coords = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 pos = textureLod(sampler2D(posTex, textureSampler), coords, 0);
    vec4 normal = textureLod(sampler2D(normalTex, textureSampler), coords, 0);

    pos = vec4(0.9490196, 0.03529412, 0.5372549, 0.30588236);
    normal = vec4(0.07058824, 0.96862745, 1, 1);

    vec3 decodedPos;

    decodedPos.x = DecodeFloatRG(pos.xy);
    decodedPos.y = DecodeFloatRG(pos.zw);
    decodedPos.z = DecodeFloatRG(normal.xy);

    float x = RemapRange(decodedPos.x, 0.0f, 1.0f, -13.0f, 13.0f);
    float y = RemapRange(decodedPos.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, -13.0f, 13.0f);
    float z = RemapRange(decodedPos.z, 0.0f, 1.0f, -13.0f, 13.0f);

    gl_Position = vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
```

Texture 1:

[image: Texture 1]

Texture 2:

[image: Texture 2]

[Google Drive With Textures, Obj, and Metadata](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dMeRA4rvLazdgrUlYt3kTp1rB9q6UqEP?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, This code block need to be

```cs
            var posTex = new Veldrid.ImageSharp.ImageSharpTexture(posPath, false, true);
            var normalTex = new Veldrid.ImageSharp.ImageSharpTexture(normalPath, false, true);

            var posDeviceTex = posTex.CreateDeviceTexture(gd, gd.ResourceFactory);
            var normalDeviceTex = normalTex.CreateDeviceTexture(gd, gd.ResourceFactory);

            var posViewDesc = new TextureViewDescription(posDeviceTex, PixelFormat.R8_G8_B8_A8_UNorm);
            var normalViewDesc = new TextureViewDescription(normalDeviceTex, PixelFormat.R8_G8_B8_A8_UNorm);

            positionTexture = gd.ResourceFactory.CreateTextureView(posViewDesc);
            normalTexture = gd.ResourceFactory.CreateTextureView(normalViewDesc);
```

Instead. While fixing this someone also mentioned I needed to declare my TextureViews before my sampler if I wanted to use the same sampler for both textureViews.

as far as gl_VertexIndex goes I'm looking into how to map the data into a spare uv channel instead as this should always be available in any game engine.